What are git-ref and git-ref-short tags in maven pom file
In spring boot application, we are using git-ref and git-ref-short tags in maven pom file as shown below:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalProperties>
                                <git-ref>${git.commit.id.full}</git-ref>
                                <git-ref-short>${git.commit.id.abbrev}</git-ref-short>
                                <version>${version}-${git.commit.id.abbrev}</version>
                            </additionalProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

I understand that we are using git-commit-id-plugin pluign as well that is generating these properties in git.properties file in project output directory e.g.
<generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>

My question is how the git-ref tags works. From which path, it fetches values. Any documentation?

The first thing why is repacke configured to skip? Usually only the build-info is required and have you configured the git-commit-id-plugin in your build?

I understand, it should not be skipped.
Yes, we have configured the git-commit-id plugin in our maven

Can you explain what you mean by: git-ref tags ?

Basically the maven-git-commit-id-plugin will generate the git.properties file when u specify the generateGitPropertiesFile property to true. Docs
<configuration>
  <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
</configuration>

And this file must be loaded into your applications using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer using like below example code
    @Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propsConfig 
      = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propsConfig.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("git.properties"));
    propsConfig.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    propsConfig.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propsConfig;
}

From the above code i see you are using git reference tags to get the info for commit/tag during the build

<git-ref> (Git Reference) is tag that could refer to a branch name, tag name, commit hash, or any other Git reference that identifies a specific state in the repository's history.

<git-ref-short> is a tag to get the shortened commit hash and usually commits hashes are typically 40-character strings



What is the purpose of git-ref tag. What does it do.

updated my answer @Moazzam
